# Load <input type="button"> link instead of <tr> link

Tags: html, forms, button, anchor

I have a form with a lot of table row `<tr>`.

each `<tr>` as a `button` and a `link`.

here is a little of my code

```
<form name="mycart" id="mycart" action="library/cartactivity.php?action=update" method="post">
   <table cellspacing="0">   
      <tr id="cart-list" onClick="document.location.href='index.php'">
         <td><button onclick="location.href='library/stockactivity.php';">Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

My problem is when I click the `<button>` It load the `<input type="submit">` link

But, I change my code to

```
<form name="mycart" id="mycart" action="library/cartactivity.php?action=update" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="0">   
       <tr id="cart-list" onClick="document.location.href='index.php'">
          <td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='library/stockactivity.php';" value="Remove" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

(I change `<button>` to `<input type="button">`)

My problem is when I click the `<input type="button">` it load the `<tr>` link

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `<a>` tag instead of `onclick`. try this

```
<a href="library/stockactivity.php" style="text-decoration: none;"><input type="button" value="Remove" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false;` to your event handler:

```
<button onclick="location.href='......'; return false;">Remove</button>
```

This will prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: Sorry, it load the `<tr>` link instead